# Gesture for specific element in custom table view cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I'm using a custom table where every cell holds several elements, one of them is a favourite "star" icon.

I want to add a tap gesture so when the star icon is tapped it would change to "unfavourite" icon (and vice versa).

I've tried to add a tap gesture in cellForRowAtIndexPath with:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer;
tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(favTapped)];
[[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1] addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
```

But tapping the icon would just call didSelectRowAtIndexPath (obviously).

My selector "favTapped" won't be called.

Any idea how to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Is user interaction enabled for the star icon?

Comment: maybe just add a UIButton as a subview to the cell?

Comment: Thanks DrBeardface!, missed it :) enabled user interaction and it works now.

Answer (score 4):

you need to add the 
`GestureRecognizer` as property to your custom cell class.

in your customCell.h:

```
' @property (weak, nonatomic ) UIButton *yourButton; // or swipeGesture'
```

in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPatch:`

```
   [cell.yourButton addTarget:self action:@selector(yourMethod) forControlEvents:yourControlEvent]; // also aviable for gestures
```

also  verify if User interaction is enabled (in your interface builder, you can also override this in your own class or). the most simple way to do this is to write in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPatch: 
[`cell.contentView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];`